# how to make UITextField disappear , how to make UITextView appear above the mapKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

UITextView is working fine if I minimize the Map, how can I make it appear above the Map?
other problem that I have is that

UITextField is not disappearing,
I 've used this
  self.myTextField.hidden = TRUE;
[myTextField resignFirstResponder];

Besides, I've released myTextField in the dealloc method and in the super view.

any help will be appreciated ...

Comment: Could you post some of the relevant code? It would make it easier to figure out what is going on... Also, what do you mean by "the Map"?

Comment: self.myTextField.hidden = FALSE;
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myTextField]; is not bringing it to front. the method bringSubviewToFront works fine with TextView but not with TextField is there something else i need to do to show or hide the TextField

Answer (score 0):

```
[view bringSubViewToFront:myTextView]
```

to bring the text field to the front? assuming the mapview is also a subview of view?

Comment: [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myTextView]; is working fine now but if i want to use it with TextField is not working, is there something special about TextField ? that causing this  this is the code i am implementing   self.myTextField.hidden = FALSE;
                       [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myTextField];